# Efficiently rotate a set of points with a rotation matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, vectorization

I have a list of 3D points stored in numpy array `A` with shape `(N,3)` and a rotation matrix `R` with shape `(3,3)`. I'd like to compute the dot product of `R.x` for each point `x` in `A` in-place. Naively I can do this:

```
for n in xrange(N):
    A[n,:] = dot(R, A[n,:])
```

Is there a way to vectorize this with a native numpy call? If it matters, N is on order of a couple thousand.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can multiply A with the transpose of the rotation matrix:

```
A = dot(A, R.T)
```

Answer (score 14):

There's a couple of minor updates/points of clarification to add to Aapo Kyrola's (correct) answer. First, the syntax of the matrix multiplication can be slightly simplified using the recently added matrix multiplication operator `@`:

```
A = A @ R.T
```

Also, you can arrange the transformation in the standard form (rotation matrix first) by taking the transpose of `A` prior to the multiplication, then transposing the result:

```
A = (R @ A.T).T
```

You can check that both forms of the transformation produce the same results via the following assertion:

```
np.testing.assert_array_equal((R @ A.T).T, A @ R.T)
```