# Efficiently rotate a set of points with a set of rotation matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotation, scientific-computing

I have a list of 3D points **p** stored in an ndarray with shape (N, 3). For each point, I have a rotation matrix **R** with shape (3,3), so the ndarray of matrices **M** has shape (N, 3, 3). I'd like to compute the dot product of **R.x** for each point **x** in **p** and each rotation **R** in **M**. Naively I can do this:

```
N = int(1e4)
p = np.random.random((N, 3))
M = np.random.random((N, 3, 3))
result = np.zeros_like(p)
for i in range(N):
    result[i, :] = np.dot(M[i, :, :], p[i, :])
```

Is there a way to do this without the python-layer for loop?

Note that this question generalizes the closely related question [Efficiently rotate a set of points with a rotation matrix in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148351/efficiently-rotate-a-set-of-points-with-a-rotation-matrix-in-numpy)

Comment: Good catch @Divakar - that question/answer exactly answers this. Thanks!